# Istio Authorization polices for memcached

Tags: istio

I am very new to Istio Authorization policies, I need some help with setting up authorization policies :

Here is the scenario:

1. I have a namespace called **namespace1** which has 4 Microservices running in them. For the context, let's call them *A,B,C,D*. And all 4 microservices have istio-sidecar injection enabled.
2. have a namespace called **namespace2** which has 2 Microservices running in them. For the context, let's call them *E,F*. And both microservices have istio-sidecar injection enabled.
3. Now I have deployed Memcached service by following [Memcached using mcrouter](https://github.com/geerlingguy/mcrouter-operator)  to namespace **memcached**. And all the pods of Memcached are also having istio-sidecar injection enabled.

Now I have a scenario where I have to allow only calls from B and C microservices in namespace1 to be made to memcached services and deny calls from A and D in namespace1 along with calls coming from any other namespaces. Is it possible to achieve this using istio authorization policies?

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: authorization-policy-deny-all
 namespace: memcached
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: activator
 action: DENY
 rules:
 - from:
   - source:
       notNamespaces: ["namespace1"]
```

This is the best I could come up with, where I am allowing only calls from namepsace1 and denying calls from all other namespaces. I could not figure out how I can deny calls from A and D Microservices in namespace1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one setup that might work.

```
--- 
spec: 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: activator
  action: ALLOW
  rules: 
    - from: 
        - source: 
            principals: 
              - cluster.local/ns/namespace1/sa/memcached--user
```

- B & C to use different service account than the rest of services. Let say the service account name is *memcached--user* (Depends on the role needed by B & C, you might want to even have separate service account for each service)
- Define AuthorizationPolicy to allow access from principal which is the service account used by B & C.
- Make sure mTLS enabled. As stated in the [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Source), This field (principals) requires mTLS enabled.
- Make sure selector is configured properly.

I hope this could solve your issue.

Comment: I think it is the "default" that every service has its own service account, so it should be `cluster.local/ns/namespace1/sa/B` afaik. After all, services have their own identity, which is one of the points of Istio

Comment: if serviceAccountName is not set in pod's spec of those services, all will use "default" serviceaccount. So, principals from A, B, C, D cert is "cluster.local/ns/namespace1/sa/default". and principal from E & F cert is ""cluster.local/ns/namespace2/sa/default"

Comment: Sure, but I didn't mean the "technical" default, but in that afaik every service should (usually) have its own service account. But you are right, I didn't even mention that connection in my answer, because I took it as granted that every service has also its own service account.

Comment: I see. in theory, yes, each service/app is better to have their own service account. in practice, it depends especially when we have thousands apps where most of them have similar requirement on roles/clusterroles to be bound to the service account.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use principals for allowing access. As for the example from the [Istio documentation on Authorization Policy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/):

so analogously something like that should be possible:

```
 - from:
   - source:
       principals: ["cluster.local/ns/namespace1/sa/B","cluster.local/ns/namespace1/sa/C"]
```

According to the doc:

```
1. If there are any DENY policies that match the request, deny the request.
2. If there are no ALLOW policies for the workload, allow the request.
3. If any of the ALLOW policies match the request, allow the request.
4. Deny the request.
```

So if you have an ALLOW policy for memcached , and allow access from B and C (rule 3), then other requests to memcached from other sources should be denied (rule 2 does not allow access, since you have an ALLOW policy).

(untested)